# why the template ui did not show the vue data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am a newbie with Vue, now I define the vue code like this:

```js
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  data: () => {
    message: "show message";
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-text="message"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

why the UI did not show the Vue data `message`? this is my sandbox version code: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-sea-snvfj?file=/src/App.vue:149-237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading the documentation on Vue [v2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) or [v3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/) on the official website - it is quite good.
Regarding your situation, it is better for you to familiarize yourself with these [sections of the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering)

Below is an example from the official website:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'show message'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```